# How to serve assets conditionally

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm building an application that has lots of web-templates that get served based on DB binding with the request's domain name. Which is straightforward job with blade.

But, how do I organize the assets of all those web-templates? Obvious route would be to move all the web-template's assets into public directory, but it's an obviously tedious workflow of rewriting paths to the assets inside the web-templates.

I would like you to tell me whether you can think of a way to serve those assets conditionally, so i can let them be siblings to the web-templates blade files inside the views directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that your app has many layouts, like css and js, and each template has the same html, but diffrent css/js ?

Comment: Each template is different single page HTML which is being supported by a different assets (html, css, js, images, fonts)